# How to proceed to set google analytics for Adobe AIR desktop app?

Tags: air, google-analytics

I am new to Adobe and google anlytics. I have seen some of the proceudres to follow to set google analytics for my desktop app on the web and I have tried some of them and the procedures have worked but no data reports has seen on my google account.

Please help and post any tutorials.

What are the ways to get the reports I have encountered with Core Reporting API but it is returning nothing i.e., 0 results.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

http://blog.leeburrows.com/2011/03/adding-google-analytics-to-a-flash-site/

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/other/flashTrackingSetupFlash

This step by step tutorial can help you.